# Incomplete Gamma Function Integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I am trying to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}e^{-bt}}{(d + et)^r} \mathrm{erfc}(\sqrt{wt}) dt = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}e^{-bt}}{(d + et)^r} \Gamma(1/2,wt) dt,
$$
where all parameters are positive. As you can see, it is evolving the incomplete gamma fcuntion/error function. I tried to look in integrals/series books to find an appropriate closed-form expression without success.

I also tried to find a series representation for the incomplete gamma function for half-integers, but no success.

I would like to ask if any solution exists ?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you're missing a factor of $\pi^{-1/2}$ on the right side.

Comment: Have you tried using the integral expression for the erfc and/or $\Gamma$ functions, and then switching the order of integration ?